# Answer flashes orange when I click the "edit (1)" link to review a suggested edit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, answers, user-interface, popups

When opening the popup to review a suggested edit, after following a direct link to an answer, the answer will briefly flash orange when the popup opens.

---

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. You need enough reputation to [review suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) (2k on graduated sites, 1k on beta sites).
2. Find a post with an active edit suggestion, e.g. through the [suggested edits review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits).  It can be either a question or an answer (but if it's a question, it needs to have at least one answer).  Open it in a new page.
3. If the edit suggestion was on a question, use the "share" link below one of the answers to obtain a link to the answer and follow it.  Either way, you should end up on a page with a URL like this:

   ```
   http://<site>.com/questions/<questionid>/<title>/<answerid>#<answerid>
   ```

   and the answer the URL points to should briefly flash orange when you load the page.
4. Now click on the "edit (1)" link to open a popup that shows the edit suggestion.
5. Observe that, as the popup opens, the answer again flashes orange in the background.

Comment: I just pretty much rewrote your report, after spending a while trying to figure out exactly how to reproduce this bug. I *hope* the reproduction instructions should be clearer now, but feel free to edit them yourself if you don't like what I've done to your bug report. :)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Much better!

Answer (score 3):

This bug appears to be caused by the third-party [history.js library](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js), included in [review JS bundle](http://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/review.en.js), triggering a spurious `hashchange` event when it's loaded.  This event then triggers the `hashchange.highlightDestination` handler defined in the [main JS bundle](http://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js) that highlights the "new" target answer.

I haven't dug deep enough into the history.js code to figure out *why* this spurious event is being triggered.  It appears to be some kind of a workaround for something (which is not really surprising, seeing as the whole library is basically a pile of workarounds and polyfills), but I'm not even sure *which* of the several `trigger()` calls in the code is the one that's causing this behavior.  I did capture a stack trace by hooking into `jQuery.trigger()`, but since it's on the minified code, it's somewhat less than perfectly helpful:

```
$.fn.trigger()              debugger eval code:1
n.Adapter.trigger()         review.en.js:1
f.initCore/<()              review.en.js:1
f.Callbacks/n()             jquery.min.js:2
f.Callbacks/o.add()         jquery.min.js:2
f</e.prototype.ready()      jquery.min.js:2
f</e.prototype.init()       jquery.min.js:2
f</e()                      jquery.min.js:2
n.Adapter.onDomLoad()       review.en.js:1
f.initCore()                review.en.js:1
f.init()                    review.en.js:1
<anonymous>                 review.en.js:1
<anonymous>                 review.en.js:1
```

Anyway, this information should at least be enough to kluge up a hotfix for [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).  Stay tuned!

---

...and here's the hotfix:

```js
// the initial hashchange event has already fired, so we can safely ignore any later
// events that don't correspond to an actual change in the hash
var oldHash = location.hash;
( $._data(window, 'events').hashchange || [] ).forEach( function (h) {
    if ( ! h.namespace || h.namespace !== 'highlightDestination' ) return;
    var oldHandler = h.handler;
    h.handler = function (e) {
        if ( oldHash === location.hash ) return;
        oldHash = location.hash;
        return oldHandler.apply( this, arguments );
    };
} );
```

This code monkey-patches the `hashchange.highlightDestination` event handler to ignore any spurious `hashchange` events that don't correspond to an actual change in the URL hash.  It's been added to the SOUP development branch, and will be part of the next stable SOUP release, v1.40.